# Creating a dummy variable in Pandas without making copies

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to create a dummy variable in Pandas that takes the value 1 if any of 5 columns of text contain a particular string. I'm using the following code:

```
df[a]=np.where((df['col1']==string) | (df['col2']==string) | (df['col3']==string) | (df['col4']==string) | (df['col5']==string),1,0)
```

This works great, but it is hugely memory intensive. I am doing this about a thousand times on a biggish dataset but the size shouldn't be unmanageable - it's about a gig to start (~1 million rows).

It seems to me that the code above must be creating copies somehow, because the memory usage on my machine grows to 80 gigs (real and virtual) and this causes problems. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why not create an extra column that evaluates to `1` or `0` if the row meets your condition/s, and check from there?

Comment: @AustinC which version of Pandas and Numpy are you using?

Comment: Numpy is 1.8.0, Pandas is 0.14.0

Comment: This sounds like a but, try upgrading to the latest pandas version

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you could do it iteratively.  Usually we try to avoid iteration, but in cases where the full vector operation uses too much memory, it is worth taking a few steps.   That especially true when working with structure fields, which aren't easily vectorized.

```
I = np.zeros(df.shape, bool)
for name, val in zip(df.dtype.names, [string1, string2, string3, ...]):
    I |= (df[name]==val)
```

Answer (score 0):

A quicker method would be to use `np.any` and just test the entire df (or a subset by passing a list of column names to subset the df):

```
In [27]:

t=['hellos','python']
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':t, 'b':t, 'c':['hello', 'yes']})
df
Out[27]:
        a       b      c
0  hellos  hellos  hello
1  python  python    yes
In [28]:

np.any(df=='hello')
Out[28]:
True
```